# prove that $\arcsin (3/5) /\pi $ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

I was asked to prove that on the unit circle, the rational points are dense. My idea is to first show that the point (3/5,4/5) corresponds to an irrational angle (more precisely, its ratio with respect to $\pi$), then by rotation, its image will be dense on the circle. This is Kronecker's theorem?

So I have to show that the angle is irrational.

Comment: You could use Niven's Theorem, which looks to have a quite elementary proof: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Niven%27s_Theorem.

Answer (score 4):

You can prove the result you actually want without any extra tools like Kronecker's theorem.

Given a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the unit circle, it will lie on the line $y = mx - 1$, where $m = \frac{y_0+1}{x_0}$. If you replace $m$ by a rational approximation to $m$, you get a line that passes through $(0,-1)$ and a rational point on the unit circle close to $(x_0,y_0)$. The rational point can be made arbitrarily close to $(x_0,y_0)$ by making the rational approximation to $m$ sufficiently good.

Answer (score 2):

By [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem) the only rational values taken by $\cos$ or $\sin$ on rational multiples of $\pi$ are $\pm 1$, $\pm 1/2$ and $0$.  In particular, $3/5$ and $4/5$ are not the sine or cosine of a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\alpha/\pi$ is rational iff $e^{i \alpha}$ is an $n$th root of unity for some $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. Maybe you can show that, if $$z = \frac{3 + 4i}{5},$$ then $z^n \neq 1$ for any $n \geq 2$.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  However, I don't see any obvious way of showing the assertion.  I spent a couple of minutes considering how much trouble it would be to show that the imaginary part of $\left[\sum_{k=0}^n (i)^k(4/5)^k (3/5)^{(n-k)}\binom{n}{k}\right]$ is not equal to $0$, but I don't see anything obvious here.